# SwiftUI & CloudKit - CoreData Many to Many Relationships

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I am new to Swift UI and working as well for the first time with CoreData and CloudKit. A lot of my questions could already be answered by existing tutorials or similiar already answered questions. But I couldnt find a great resource for Many to Many Relationships in CoreData.

In my project the user can save markers/timestamps by pushing a button, which triggers a function saving the data in CoreData. When the recording, during the user can save timestamps, is finished by a button press a function saves the recording to CoreData. My aim is that the recording saves and includes all created and saved markers/timestamps, so the user can click in i his history on a Project/Recording and gets all markers/timestamps for this recodring.

At that point I can save and create a marker and recording but not link them to each other.

How can I do it the easiest way - with a Many to Many Relationship? How do Many to Many Relationships work in my code?

I would be really thankfull for help and ideas!

Robert
PS: On the phtos you can see that I already tried to create Relationships, but I can't create them with a function...

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxkfZ.png)

[Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8pTu.png)

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA15r.png)

Comment: Please can you post the code as text, rather than links to pictures - it is much easier to review.  As regards your model, it looks to me like your relationship should be one-many, not many-many: each recording can have many markers, but each marker relates to only one recording?

Comment: Hi at first place thanks for the fast feedback!
Concerning the type of relationships: I have Marker (for example: Intro, Mute, Edit, ChapterMark) which can be used in many projects.
I think it could also be a one-many relationship with a rule that if the projet is deleted the marker is not.
Unfortunately the whole  code  from the screenshots is too long for here,  can you name a part you would like to have?

Comment: So are you saying that Intro, Mute, Edit, ChapterMark etc are instances of a `Marker` entity, and your `UsedMarker` entity represents the use of one Marker Instance, for one Recording, at a given timestamp?

Comment: Yes. The Marker itself with his color, name and icon is stored in the MarkerItem entity and when i use it it gives over his values + the timestamp and is saved in the UsedMarker entity.
I made a video from the app, maybe it helps you better to understand. As you can see the Projects/Recordings are a now in a ForEach and not fetched, because I can't link the used markers to recording and save it...
https://youtu.be/MXmUI6kTCpo

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your `UsedMarker` represents the use of a particular `MarkerItem`, at a particular `timestamp`, of a particular `Recording`.  Hence I would model the relationship from `UsedMarker` to `Recording` as to-one.

Looking at your current model, the `UsedMarker` has attributes for the colour, name and icon, which you describe as coming from the `MarkerItem` entity.  I would avoid that duplication, and replace those attributes with a to-one relationship from `UsedMarker` to `MarkerItem`.

Defining the relationships in code is quite straight forward when they are `to-one`.  If you have a `Recording` object, say `currentRecording`, and the user adds a particular `MarkerItem`, say `chosenMarker`, at a given timestamp, then you can create a new `UsedMarker` at assign the relationships:

```
let useMarker = UsedMarker(context: self.context)
useMarker.recording = currentRecording
useMarker.markerItem = chosenMarker
useMarker.id = UUID()
useMarker.hours = ... // etc
```